# How to calculate diode circuit analysis (novice)

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, circuit-design

[image: Diode]

In my electronic course, we have just begun learning about diodes. I tried to solve some diode examples but I need help with this question.I tried to solve for 2 states (ON and OFF state) but I did not find break point (Vanode>Vcathode) I used node voltage theorem and mesh current theorem.I also tried apply to Kirchhoff. **How can I calculate Vo and break point**
(I am not asking for homework help)

[image: diode2]

I added my soluiton

Comment: Ignore the diode for now (consider it an open circuit). What do the voltages look like at either end of the diode?

Comment: I found Vo point is -1V and other point is (if Vi=20V) 18.3V so diode is off state for Vi=20V But how can I calculate break point? @Stiddily

Comment: I added my solution can you help me?@Stiddily

Comment: @KağanDoğan It's really simple. You have a resistor divider at top. Just convert that to its Thevenin. Also do the same thing for the +15 V and the sin() function. Now you have a very, very simple series circuit to analyze. The answer just quite literally falls out from there. If you cannot see it, I'll draw up the evolved schematic for you as an answer. But frankly, you should be able to "see" this.

Comment: Try setting Vi to 10V and assume that the diode is forward biased. Find the value of the forward current through the diode. If you find that the forward current is negative then if means that the diode can not be forward biased. Repeat for Vi = -10V.

Comment: @KağanDoğan What do you specifically mean by “break point”? Do you mean the instantaneous value of the sinusoidal input voltage where the diode changes of state? Or the breakdown voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I calculate Vo and break point

Short answer:

- For the output voltage, you could use the *[assumed states method](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/electronics/4-4-assumed-states-method-hz5cM)*. You assume a state for the diode (either ON or OFF) in a given time interval, then solve the circuit for the output voltage, using the typical methods such as nodal analysis, network reduction, etc.; and then check if the initial assumption is true. If true, the output voltage you calculated is the correct one. If false, the output voltage is wrong, and you have to assume the other possible state for the diode and solve the circuit again. You repeat this process for each time interval.
- For the transition voltage (what I think you meant by *break point*) and the intervals of conduction, determine the value of the sinusoidal input voltage in which the diode changes of state, which happens when the diode is forward-biased (0.7 V across it) but carrying no current; that’s the transition voltage. Then, find the two corresponding instants or angles in which the input voltage crosses such value; that gives you the intervals of conduction.

The analytical/exact expression of the output voltage is shown in equation (22) below, near the end of this answer; its plot is shown in figure 11, and a simulation in figure 12. The transition voltage is exactly −10.05 V, which occurs at about 210.17° and 329.83°.

For the long answer, keep reading.

---

## 1. Basics

### 1.1. The example/exercise circuit

The given circuit can be redrawn as shown in the following figure.

[image: Figure 1]

*Figure 1. Circuit diagram of the example circuit. Image source: own, made with Falstad's free online circuit simulator.*

### 1.2. The simplified model of a silicon rectifier diode

Given that the text of the exercise specifies \$V_\gamma = 0.7 \text{ V}\$ without anything else, we may assume the diode model to be used is the simplified model. I briefly discussed the various models for rectifier diodes, including equations, diagrams and voltage-current plots in [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-three-diode-approximations/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).

In that model, the rectifier diode is governed by the two following simultaneous equations, for the ON/forward-bias and OFF/reverse-bias states:

\$v(t) = V_\gamma \iff i(t) \ge 0 \tag 1\$

\$v(t) \le V_\gamma \iff i(t) = 0 \tag 2\$

The equivalent circuits of this model are the following.

[image: Figure 2]

*Figure 2. Circuit diagram of the equivalent circuits of the simplified model of a real diode:* a) *equivalent circuit in the OFF region;* b) *equivalent circuit in the ON region as well as when \$v = i = 0\$. Image source: own, made with PowerPoint.*

The characteristics curve (\$i\$-\$\$v plot) of this model is the following.

[image: Figure 3]

*Figure 3. Characteristics curve of the simplified model of a real diode. Image source: own, made with GeoGebra.*

### 1.3. How to analyze a circuit with diodes, resistors and AC sources

For a short tutorial on analyzing circuits with diodes, read [this answer](http://The%20equivalent%20circuits%20of%20this%20model%20are%20shown%20next.) and watch [this video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/electronics/4-4-assumed-states-method-hz5cM).

### 1.4. How to determine the transition voltage

For determining the value of the input voltage where the diode changes state, we look at the characteristics curve of the diode model (figure 3), and note that the change in state occurs at the point \$(V_\gamma, 0)\$, *i.e*. when \$v(t) = V_\gamma\$ and \$i(t) = 0\$. So, we assume those values for the diode: it is forward-biased but not carrying any current. Such value of the input voltage is called as *transition voltage* by Robert Boylestad and  Louis Nashelsky in section 2.8 (pages 78-80) of their textbook *Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory* (11th edition); I imagine this is what you meant by *break point* in the post.

## 2. Analyzing the circuit

### 2.1. Output voltage at \$t = 0\$

#### 2.1.1. Assuming the diode is ON

Now, let's start analyzing the circuit. I'll ignore units. We start at the time instant \$t = 0\$. We can arbitrarily assume the state of the diode, and then check if the assumption was correct. Let's assume the diode is ON. Therefore, we substitute it in figure 1 with its equivalent circuit in the ON state (figure 2*b)*), and we get the following equivalent circuit.

[image: Figure 4]

*Figure 4. Circuit diagram of the example circuit when the diode is ON.*

Fortunately the circuit doesn't contain energy-storage elements (capacitors and inductors), which would make significantly harder to analyze the circuit.

Now we solve the circuit of figure 4 for the desired signals (\$v_\text{o}\$), and we also for \$i_\text{D}\$ since we must confirm if the assumption of the ON state is actually true.

We can perform nodal analysis, choosing the reference node to be the lower node, and arbitrarily assuming the direction for the currents in each branch, as shown in figure 4.

Applying KCL at the node of \$v_\text{o}\$ (and Ohm's law and KVL):

\$+ \dfrac{3 - v_\text{o}}{2 \, 000} - i_\text{D} - \dfrac{v_\text{o} - (-3)}{1 \, 000} = 0 \tag 3\$

Applying KCL at the node of \$v_\text{K}\$:

\$+ \dfrac{v_\text{i} - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + i_\text{D} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag 4\$

Expressing the source voltage \$V_\gamma = 0.7 \text{ V}\$ in terms of the two adjacent nodal voltages by using KVL:

\$0.7 = v_\text{o} - v_\text{K} \tag 5\$

We substitute \$v_\text{i}(t) = 20 \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ V}\$ for \$v_\text{i}(0) = 20 \sin{(\omega \cdot 0)} \text{ V} = 0 \text{ V}\$ in equation (4):

\$+ \dfrac{0 - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + i_\text{D} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag 6\$

Now we have three equations ((3), (5), (6)) with three unknowns (\$v_\text{o}\$, \$i_\text{D}\$, \$v_\text{K}\$), so we can solve those equations for those variables. [After doing so with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems%20of%20equations%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22%2B%20%283%20-%20x%29%2F2000%20-%20y%20-%20%28x%20%2B%203%29%2F1000%20%3D%200%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%22%2B%20%280%20-%20z%29%2F1000%20%2B%20y%20%2B%20%2815%20-%20z%29%2F2000%20%3D%200%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation3%22%7D%20-%3E%220.7%20%3D%20x%20-%20z%22), we get:

\$v_\text{o} = \dfrac{47}{20} \text{ V} = 2.35 \text{ V} \tag*{} \$

\$i_\text{D} = - \dfrac{201}{40 \, 000} \text{ A} = - 0.005025 \text{ A} = - 5.025 \text{ mA} \tag*{}\$

According to equation (2), the assumption of the ON state is true if \$i_\text{D} > 0\$. But we got \$i_\text{D} = - 5.025 \text{ mA} < 0\$, so the assumption is wrong, and the computed value of \$v_\text{o}\$ is in general wrong.

#### 2.1.2. Assuming the diode is OFF

At least now we know the diode must be in the OFF state at \$t = 0\$ (since that's the other possible state). Therefore, we substitute it in figure 1 with its equivalent circuit in the OFF state (figure 2*a)*), and we get the following equivalent circuit.

[image: Figure 5]

*Figure 4. Circuit diagram of the example circuit when the diode is OFF.*

Again we apply nodal analysis (or any other technique you want).

Applying KCL at the node of \$v_\text{o}\$ (and Ohm's law and KVL):

\$+ \dfrac{3 - v_\text{o}}{2 \, 000} - \dfrac{v_\text{o} - (-3)}{1 \, 000} = 0 \tag 7\$

Applying KCL at the node of \$v_\text{K}\$:

\$+ \dfrac{v_\text{i} - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag 8\$

At \$t = 0\$, \$v_\text{i(t)} = 0\$, so equation (8) becomes:

\$+ \dfrac{0 - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag 9\$

Solving equations (7) and (9) for \$v_\text{o}\$ and \$v_\text{K}\$ [with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems%20of%20equations%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22%2B%20%283%20-%20x%29%2F2000%20-%20%28x%20%2B%203%29%2F1000%20%3D%200%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%22%2B%20%280%20-%20z%29%2F1000%20%2B%20%2815%20-%20z%29%2F2000%20%3D%200%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation3%22%7D%20-%3E%220.7%20%3D%20x%20-%20z%22), we get:

\$v_\text{o} = -1 \text{ V} \tag*{} \$

\$v_\text{K} = 5 \text{ V} \tag*{}\$

The voltage across the diode is:

\$v_\text{D} = v_\text{o} - v_\text{K} = (-1) - (5) = -6 \text{ V} \tag*{}\$

According to equation (2), the assumption of the OFF state is true if \$v_\text{D} < 0\$. We got \$v_\text{D} = - 56 \text{ V} < 0\$, so the assumption is correct, and the computed value of \$v_\text{o}\$ is correct. Thus:

\$v_\text{o}(0) = -1 \text{ V} \tag {10} \$

### 2.2. Output voltage for \$0 \le t \le t_1\$

#### 2.2.1. Assuming the diode is OFF

Now that we've determined the state of the diode at the beginning of a cycle of the sinusoidal input voltage, we can find the output voltage as long as the diode is OFF. The circuit of figure 5 is true as long as the diode is OFF. While we know the diode is OFF at \$t = 0\$, how do we know for long it will stay OFF? For the rest of the cycle? Or for a shorter interval of time? Regardless of that, we may denote by \$t_1\$ the instant of time where the diode becomes ON for the first time in the cycle. So, for \$0 \le t \le t_1\$, the circuit is correctly described by figure 5. The nodal equations are the same, except now we solve them without substituting \$t = 0\$, instead we substitute \$v_\text{i}(t) = 20 \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ V}\$ in equation (8):

\$+ \dfrac{20 \sin{(\omega t)} - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag {11}\$

Solving equations (7) and (11) for \$v_\text{o}\$ and \$v_\text{K}\$ with Wolfram Mathematica, we get:

\$v_\text{o}(t) = -1 \text{ V} \quad \text{, $0 \le t \le t_1$} \tag {12} \$

as shown in the following figure.

[image: Figure 6]

*Figure 6.*

### 2.3. \$t_1\$

Let's determine the value of the instant \$t_1\$ where the diodes changes to the ON state. To do that, first we find the transition voltage. We assume the diode is ON, but carrying no current. We had already analyzed the circuit when the diode was ON (figure 3), so we can use the same equations we obtained in that state, and set the diode current to zero (\$i_\text{D} = 0\$). Thus equations (3) and (4) become:

\$+ \dfrac{3 - v_\text{o}}{2 \, 000} - \dfrac{v_\text{o} - (-3)}{1 \, 000} = 0 \tag {13}\$

\$+ \dfrac{v_\text{i} - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag {14}\$

Now we solve equations (13), (14) and (5) for \$v_\text{i}\$ with Wolfram Mathematica:

\$v_\text{i} = V_\text{tran} = -10.05 \text{ V} \tag {15} \$

as shown in the following figure.

[image: Figure 7]

*Figure 7.*

In other words, **the transition voltage (the break point?) is −10.05 V**. This means that, whenever the sinusoidal input voltage passes through −10.05 V (either increasing or decreasing), the diode will change of state.

From the transition voltage, we can find \$t_1\$. We substitute the expression of the input voltage in equation (15) and solve it for \$t\$:

\$t_1 = \dfrac{\sin^{-1}{(201/400)}}{\omega} + \dfrac{\pi \text{ rad}}{\omega} \approx \dfrac{3.6681 \text{ rad}}{\omega} \tag {16}\$

as shown in the following figure.

[image: figure 8]

*Figure 8.*

In other words, **in the first cycle of the sinusoidal input voltage, the first time the diode changes from OFF to ON state is at \$t \approx 3.6681/\omega\$ or \$\omega t \approx 3.6681 \approx 210.17^\circ\$**.

### 2.4. Output voltage for \$t_1 \le t \le t_2\$

#### 2.4.1. Assuming the diode is ON

We've determined the diode changes state whenever the input voltage crosses −10.05 V. This happens twice per cycle. Therefore, the diode will change of state twice per cycle. First the diode is turned OFF, then it turns ON at \$t_1\$, then it should turn OFF again at \$t_2\$, and it stays turned OFF until \$T\$ (the end of the cycle).

We had already analyzed the circuit when the diode was ON (figure 3), so we can use the same equations we obtained in that state. Substituting \$v_\text{i(t)} = 20 \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ V}\$ in equation (4):

\$+ \dfrac{20 \sin{(\omega t)} - v_\text{K}}{1 \, 000} + i_\text{D} + \dfrac{15 - v_\text{K}}{2 \, 000} = 0 \tag {17}\$

Solving equations (3), (5) and (17) for \$v_\text{o}\$, \$i_\text{D}\$ and \$v_\text{K}\$ with Wolfram Mathematica, we get:

\$v_\text{o} = \dfrac{47}{20} \text{ V} + \dfrac{20}{3} \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ V} \tag*{} \$

\$i_\text{D} = - \dfrac{201}{40 \, 000} \text{ A} - \dfrac{1}{100} \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ A} \tag {18}\$

as shown in the following figure.

[image: Figure 9]

*Figure 9.*

According to equation (2), the assumption of the ON state is true as long as \$i_\text{D} > 0\$. We got equation (19), which is positive from \$\omega t = \omega t_1 \approx 3.6681 \text{ rad}\$ to about \$\omega t \approx 5.7 \text{ rad}\$, as we can see in the following figure, so the assumption is correct and the diode turns OFF t about 5.7 rad, and the computed value of \$v_\text{o}\$ is correct. Thus:

\$v_\text{o}(t) = \dfrac{47}{20} \text{ V} + \dfrac{20}{3} \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ V} \quad \text{, $t_1 \le t \le t_2$} \tag {19} \$

[image: Figure 10]

*Figure 10.*

### 2.5. \$t_2\$

We already found the value of \$t_2\$ in figure 8:

\$t_2 = \dfrac{2 \pi \text{ rad}}{\omega} - \dfrac{\sin^{-1}{(201/400)}}{\omega} \approx \dfrac{5.7567 \text{ rad}}{\omega} \tag {20}\$

In other words, **in the first cycle of the sinusoidal input voltage, the first time the diode changes from ON to OFF state is at \$t \approx 5.7567/\omega\$ or \$\omega t \approx 5.7567 \approx 329.83^\circ\$**.

### 2.6. Output voltage for \$t_2 \le t \le T\$

#### 2.6.1. Assuming the diode is OFF

Since the diode is OFF, the expression for the output voltage during this time interval is the same as during the time interval \$0 \le t \le t_1\$, so we can repeat equation (12):

\$v_\text{o}(t) = -1 \text{ V} \quad \text{, $t_2 \le t \le T$} \tag {21}\$

### 2.7 Output voltage for any instant of the first cycle

Now we can combine all the equations: (12), (16), (19), (20), (21). Finally, *the output voltage for the first cycle is*:

\$\boxed{v_\text{o}(t) = \begin{cases} -1 \text{ V} & \text{, $0 \le t \le \dfrac{\sin^{-1}{(201/400)} + \pi \text{ rad}}{\omega}$} \\ \dfrac{47}{20} \text{ V} + \dfrac{20}{3} \sin{(\omega t)} \text{ V} & \text{, $\dfrac{\sin^{-1}{(201/400)} + \pi \text{ rad}}{\omega} \le t \le \dfrac{2 \pi \text{ rad} - \sin^{-1}{(201/400)}}{\omega}$} \\ -1 \text{ V} & \text{, $\dfrac{2 \pi \text{ rad} - \sin^{-1}{(201/400)}}{\omega} \le t \le 2 \pi/\omega$} \end{cases}} \tag {22}\$

Here is a plot in Wolfram Mathematica of the input and output voltages:

[image: Figure 11]

*Figure 11.*

Here is a simulation in LTspice:

[image: Figure 12]

*Figure 12.*

Comment: The result can be had with far, far, far less work than this.

Comment: Probably. If you don’t want (or aren’t asked) to find an exact result, yes. If you don’t want to prove the states you assumed during the analysis were correct, yes. If you want to simplify the circuit before starting to solve for the output voltage, yes. If you can run a simulation before even solving the circuit, yes. What I wanted to show is a general procedure for any network (that has resistors, diodes and AC and DC sources), not just this one. For networks with inductors and capacitors, the method still applies, though we have to also find initial and possibly final conditions,

Comment: Furthermore. If you don’t want to explain the basics as I did in section 1 of my answer, yes, remove that. If you don’t want to show the waveforms nor the simulation, yes. If you don’t want to show the computations in Mathematica, yes. I would like to see you explain how the circuit can be solved, determine the exact expression for the output voltage and the transition voltage without first running a simulation (since that shows the answer and is cheating), explain how to obtain each equation, prove that each state you assumed is correct, plot the waveforms, and show a simulation. :)

Comment: The only thing I want to add is that I didn't downvote your answer. That was someone else. Just so you know. (I only very rarely downvote answers.)

Answer (score 2):

Just take the Thevenin at both sides and you go from the left side to the right side:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhygiW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a really easy circuit to analyse. The only way the series circuit has any current in it, at all, is when the sum of \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$ (on the right) is below \$-1\:\text{V}\$. At other times, the diode \$D_1\$ blocks and the output must remain at \$-1\:\text{V}\$. When the summed condition does apply so as to any allow current because of a forward-biased diode, then the voltage difference (between \$-1\:\text{V}\$ and whatever the forward-biasing voltage is at the other end, less the diode drop) is divided by the remaining (trivial) resistor divider before adding that back to \$-1\:\text{V}\$.

(The DC bias, \$V_2\$, is readily achieved by assuming the mean value for \$V_{_\text{I}}\$, which obviously is \$0\:\text{V}\$, on the left side schematic. The only complexity is that the diode voltage isn't really a constant, but varies with the current through it. But that's not something you care about for your analysis.)

Comment: Nice, but: 1) You didn’t explain how you obtained the Thévenin equivalent network. 2) You didn’t explain why the diode conducts when \$V_2 +V_3 < -1\$ in your right diagram. 3) You didn’t explain how to compute (nor which is) the transition voltage of the sinusoidal source, which I think the asker wanted to know (what he called the “break point”). 4) You didn’t explain how to compute (nor which are) the intervals of conduction, which the asker wanted to know (his image said “but how can I find interval”). 5) I think you didn’t explain how to compute (nor which is) the output voltage.

Comment: @AlejandroNava It's actually trivial. But the OP has made a selection. So things done are done.